# Custom paging plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to build custom paging plugin in jquery. I have write some code but I stuck in one place like my paging default number is 10 page when user click on greater then page 8 then it should show two further page. Expected result shown below. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdsdafLr/)

[image: default display]
[image: When the 9th page is selected]
[image]

```
$(function(){
$.fn.pageing= function(options){
var settings =$.extend({
// These are the defaults.
totalPage: $(this).find('li').length,
currentpage: 2,
defaultdisplay:10
}, options), el= this;

var defaultFunction= {
showDefault: function(){
for(i=0; i<(settings.defaultdisplay);i++){

$(el).find('li').eq(i).show()
}   
},
selectCurrentPage: function (){ 
$(el).find('li:eq('+settings.currentpage+')').addClass('active')
}
}

defaultFunction.showDefault();
defaultFunction.selectCurrentPage();
}

$('ul').pageing({defaultdisplay:10})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on this more and find one solution. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdsdafLr/)

```
$(function(){

var apply= {
    init: function (settings){
    if(apply.isnegative(settings.moving-settings.defaultdisplay) && settings.currentpage>settings.moving){
            apply.nextpage=Math.abs(settings.moving-settings.currentpage);
            apply.moveto=Math.abs(settings.moving-settings.currentpage);
    }
    for(apply.nextpage; apply.nextpage<(settings.defaultdisplay+apply.moveto);apply.nextpage++){
    $(this).find('li').eq(apply.nextpage).show()
    }       
    $(this).find('li:eq('+settings.currentpage+')').addClass('active');

    },

    isnegative: function(val){
        if(val > -1)
        return false
        else 
        return true
        },
        nextpage:0,
        moveto:0

}

$.fn.pageing= function(options){
var settings =$.extend({
// These are the defaults.
totalPage: $(this).find('li').length,
currentpage: 8,
defaultdisplay:10,
moving:7
}, options), el= this;
apply.init.call(this,settings)
}

$('ul').pageing({defaultdisplay:10})
})

</script>

</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>14</li>
<li>15</li>
<li>16</li>
</ul>
```